# Set Fix special price for Bundle Product instead of the percentage

Tags: bundled-product, tierprice, special-price

I want to set the fixed special price and fixed customer group price instead of the percentage. Please check the attached screenshot,

[image]

Default Bundle product does not have the functionality to set the special price and customer group price as fixed along with Discount.

So, I want to implement this custom functionality. Can anyone guide me? Also this price should be consider as a final price after adding product to the cart.

If you have any alternate solution to achieve this functionality then let me know. Ultimately client want to display the special price on PDP.

**Note:** They are syncing the product from Netsuite and there already fixed price set.
Your help would be appreciated.

Thanks,